# VBA crops shapes (OLEobjects and Charts) involuntarily

Tags: excel, vba, crop, powerpoint, shapes

I have been experiencing the following problem.

I use a VBA to update Powerpoint deck with user-selected information. Users choose selected data, refresh the appropriate tables/graphs and these are then updated in the Powerpoint. Some of the users are experiencing an issue, where the deck is updated, but the OLEobjects (charts, Excel tables) are cropped.

I have been using the following code to store the size and positions of the updated shapes. It works for majority of users, but in a few cases it seems like the program is resizing the objects, but stores them in predefined placeholders, so they are positioned correctly on the slides, but are cropped (like they are zoomed by about 10 to 20 percent).

Any help here is appreciated.

```
 For Each aSlide In pptPresentation.Slides
        For Each aShape In aSlide.Shapes
            With aShape
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Tags.Add Name:="L", Value:=CStr(.Left)
                .Tags.Add Name:="T", Value:=CStr(.Top)
                .Tags.Add Name:="H", Value:=CStr(.Height)
                .Tags.Add Name:="W", Value:=CStr(.Width)
            End With
        Next
    Next        

'Update slides in PowerPoint Presentation with new content
For Each aSlide In pptPresentation.Slides
    For Each aShape In aSlide.Shapes
        If (aShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject) Or (aShape.Type = msoChart) Then
                aShape.LinkFormat.Update
        End If
    Next
Next

pptPresentation.UpdateLinks

For Each aSlide In pptPresentation.Slides
        For Each aShape In aSlide.Shapes
            With aShape
                ' skip untagged shapes:
                sTest = .Tags("L") & .Tags("T") & .Tags("H") & .Tags("W")
                If Len(sTest) > 0 Then
                    .Left = CSng(.Tags("L"))
                    .Top = CSng(.Tags("T"))
                    .Height = CSng(.Tags("H"))
                    .Width = CSng(.Tags("W"))
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and from what I learned it appears when you change the zoom factor on your Excel workbook. When you paste the object and link it, the zoom factor that it was at is carried over with the link. If you change the zoom factor in your Excel workbook, so you go from 100% to 150%, it will carry over the new zoom factor when you update the link.

***The only real solution is to make sure that people don't change the zoom factor on the Excel workbook.***

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I have been suspecting after a few hours of browsing the internet for such a problem. Though I was under the impression that only the zoom factor of the sheet, on which the original object sits, is causing the problem. Is there some clean way of having the zoom factor set to not change? Because I believe the change of the objects happens even if the users don't change the zoom factor in Excel before running the code.